# How to check in realtime if Location services switched off by user in a tracking app

Tags: android

I am developing a tracking app using fused location api. I want to check programatically if user has turned off location services while app is running.

I am thinking of running a parallel thread to check if GPS has been turned off by user in every 5 sec using method `LocationManager.isProviderEnabled()`.

Is this the right approach or there is a better way to do it?

Comment: The listener you will implement have the event you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use broadcast receiver, when GPS settings will be changed, you will get automatically notified.

here is the link:

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/manifest-receivers.html

Comment: This worked for me. I used below code private BroadcastReceiver gpsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {
                if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
                    Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: activate GPS");
                    permissionOrLocationSettingsNotification();
                }
            }
        }
    };

Comment: I can't at this moment as I am new to this site. Will do in future.

Answer (score 1):

From the [LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) documentation

> abstract void  onProviderEnabled(String provider)
>   Called when the provider is enabled by the user.
>
> abstract void  onProviderDisabled(String provider)
>   Called when the provider is disabled by the user.

So you could use those event to know if the provider you are using to listening the position is enable / disabled.

Comment: I am using FusedLocation Api so I can't implement these methods. Are LocationListeners better than FusedLocation Api?

Comment: I would say no, The API should add more precision taking datas from multiple providers. But I think this might consume more battery (not source here). I found easier to use a simple LocationListener but this is not the best practice if you listen Google ;)